# how to fix css animation when deployed

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, css-animations

I have a D3 foreignObject with some css that creates a radial progress bar. Everything works great locally but when I publish build it starts doing odd stuff.

Made some video clips
Locally Correct version
[WORKING](https://streamable.com/rrmm3z)

Deployed NOT working version
[NOT WORKING](https://streamable.com/ffrlw2)

```
    export const _tierTwoPlayButtonBorder = (
  g: d3.Selection<SVGGElement, unknown, HTMLElement, any>,
  uiTierTwoItems: UITierTwoProps[],
  theme: ExtendedTheme,
  radius: number
) =>
  g
    .selectAll(null)
    .data(uiTierTwoItems)
    .enter()
    .append('foreignObject')
    .attr('x', ({ value }) => -((radius - 15) * getCos(value)))
    .attr('y', ({ value }) => (radius + 30) * getSin(value))
    .attr('height', 36)
    .attr('width', 36)
    .append('xhtml:div')
    .attr('id', 'playme')
    .attr('class', 'none')
    .html(
      `<div class="halfclip"><div class="halfcircle" id="clipped"></div></div><div class="halfcircle" id="fixed"></div>`
    );


      #playme {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  .halfclip {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform-origin: left center;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    animation: cliprotate 4s steps(2) infinite;
  }

  .halfcircle {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    border-top-color: rgb(19, 158, 223);
    border-left-color: rgb(19, 158, 223);
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  #clipped {
    width: 200%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
  }

  #fixed {
    width: 100%;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    opacity: 1;
    animation: showfixed 4s linear infinite;
  }


  @keyframes cliprotate {
    from {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }

  @keyframes rotate {
    from {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(135deg);
    }
  }

  @keyframes showfixed {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    49.9% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

Comment: How many uiTierTwoItems are there i.e. are you creating items with duplicate id values?

Comment: There is just one item in the array.